# String.TrimStart() doesn't function as I expected, why?

Tags: string, powershell, trim

I've got the command below:

```
> "D:\abc\abcName".TrimStart("D:\abc")
Name
```

In fact I wish this to trim exactly "D:\abc" and return only "abcName" but seems that the 2nd "abc" is trimmed off as well.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

I'm using PS 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

The argument to [`TrimStart()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx) is treated as an array of `char`s, not a literal string. All consecutive characters at the start of the string that match any of the characters inside the argument "D:\abc" is removed.

You could use the `-replace` operator instead, which takes a regex pattern as its right-hand argument:

```
PS C:\> "D:\abc\abcName" -replace "^D:\\abc\\"
abcName
```

---

If you are unsure which characters to escape (such as `\`), let the [`[regex]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) class do it for you:

```
PS C:\> "D:\abc\abcName" -replace "^$([regex]::Escape("D:\abc\"))"
abcName
```

Answer (score 2):

Mathias R. Jessen points it out.

Looks like you want to get the filename from a path. Instead of using TrimStart consider use the static [GetFileNameWithoutExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.100).aspx) method:

```powershell
[system.io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension("D:\abc\abcName.bat")
```

Result:

> abcName

Or if you want the complete filename with extension:

```powershell
[system.io.path]::GetFileName("D:\abc\abcName.bat")
```

Result:

> abcName.bat